# How to trim string values recursively from a serializable JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I have a serializable JavaScript object such as

```
{
  a: 'hello ',
  b: [],
  c: 5,
  d: {
    e: '  world ';
  },
}
```

and I would like to create a JavaScript object similar to the original object except that every string value has leading and trailing whitespace removed:

```
{
  a: 'hello',
  b: [],
  c: 5,
  d: {
    e: 'world';
  },
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

`JSON.stringify` has a [`replacer` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) that we can use

```
const replacer = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value.trim();
    }
    return value;
};

const trimmedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, replacer));
```

Note that JSON does not have `undefined` values, so any keys with undefined values will be stripped out of the resulting object. You may use `null` in place of `undefined` if you wish to preserve these values and if `null` is suitable for your purposes.

```
const replacer = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value.trim();
    }
    if (value === undefined) {
        // JSON doesn't have undefined
        return null;
    }
    return value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively trim the object like so (note that my solution will mutate your initial object):

```js
let obj = {
  a: 'hello ',
  b: [" foo ", "    bar"],
  c: 5,
  d: {
    e: '  world '
  }
};

trimAll = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
      obj[key] = obj[key].trim();
    } else {
      trimAll(obj[key]);
    }
  });
}
trimAll(obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my recursive function to handle this:

```js
let x = {
  a: 'hello ',
  b: ['     hi ', 'we     '],
  c: 5,
  d: {
    e: '  world '
  },
};

function trimRecursively(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.reduce((all, item) => {
      all.push(trimRecursively(item));
      return all;
    }, []);
  } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
    return Object.keys(value).reduce((all, key) => {
      all[key] = trimRecursively(value[key]);
      return all;
    }, {});
  } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.trim();
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}

console.log(trimRecursively(x));
console.log(x);
```

My solution works for any type of `value`, and it also does not mutate the original object!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function trimAll(obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'string') obj[k] = obj[k].trim();
    else if (typeof obj[k] === 'object' && !(obj[k] instanceof Array)) trimAll(obj[k]);
  }
}
```